# css sub child ul width of its child, not parent

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, submenu

I've got a menu with multiple child elements, the problem I'm having is that the child menu is displaying as the width of its parent, not its child element.

[image]

Here's my code:

```css
#navbar ul {
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
#navbar ul li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block
}
#navbar ul li > a,
#navbar ul li > span {
    color: #004665;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 35px;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'roboto-condensed', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 72px
}
#navbar ul li.active > a,
#navbar ul li > a:hover,
#navbar ul li > a:focus {
    color: #6fbfe6;
    background: none
}
#navbar ul li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    background: #f0f5f7;
    padding: 30px 0 20px;
    border-top: solid 2px #b1b1b1;
    display: none
}
#navbar ul li > ul li {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    white-space: nowrap
}
#navbar ul li > ul li > a {
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 30px 10px;
    white-space: nowrap
}
#navbar ul li > ul li > ul {
    left: 100%;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: -32px;
    width: 100%
}
#navbar ul li > ul li > ul li.parent:hover > ul {
    display: block
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="item-120 parent">
        <a href="/">Academics</a>
        <ul class="nav-child">
            <li class="item-204 parent"><a href="/">IB Programmes</a>
            <li class="item-205 parent">
                <a href="/">VCE</a>
                <ul class="nav-child">
                    <li class="item-215"><a href="/">VCE Overview</a></li>
                    <li class="item-216"><a href="/">Outcomes and SACs</a></li>
                    <li class="item-217"><a href="/">Assessment and Scoring</a></li>
                    <li class="item-218"><a href="/">Subjects We Offer</a></li>
                    <li class="item-219"><a href="/">Who is the VCE for?</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="item-205 parent"><a href="/">Student Wellbeing</a>
            <li class="item-207 parent"><a href="/">Resource Library</a>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/fw16jw1y/

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fw16jw1y/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `width: 100%` and `right: 0` from the following code:

```
#navbar ul li > ul li > ul {
    left: 100%;
    right: 0;   /* REMOVE */
    z-index: 1000;
    top: -32px;
    width: 100%  /* REMOVE */
}
```

You are containing the `ul` element by defining `width`.

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fw16jw1y/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this,

```
nav > ul > li > ul > li > a {
    max-width: 150px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

You can reffer this post,
[Child element auto width (larger than parent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594100/child-element-auto-width-larger-than-parent) ,
[Allow absolutely positioned element to be wider than parent absolutely positioned element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606079/allow-absolutely-positioned-element-to-be-wider-than-parent-absolutely-positione)